# Follow-up 'Diophantine' question: extrapolating to the general case

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, diophantine-equations, problem-solving

I came across a problem involving a certain Diophantine equation a few days ago. I learnt quite a few extremely helpful things about them on this thread here, which I started: [A model that can be followed when solving Diophantine equations - ideas?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869267/a-model-that-can-be-followed-when-solving-diophantine-equations-ideas) -

Feel free to read it for context for what follows:

Whilst toiling with the concept of Diophantine equations I seemed to notice a surprising pattern.

Any equation of the form:

**$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{y}=\frac{3}{p}$$**

*(Where x and y are positive integers and p is a prime greater than or equal to 5)*

**always seems to have exactly 3 solutions.**

Is it possible to prove this initial hypothesis/conjecture? Or have I thought incorrectly and can you disprove me? Looking forward to seeing what the responses yield!

Comment: Do you mean "always seems to have exactly 3 solutions"?

Comment: I think so @user25406! - All the examples I tried - they all have exactly 3 solutions. No more and no less - but I wasn't sure if this was a coincidence or whether this is something that is ALWAYS the proof - hence why I was seeking a proof.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{y}=\frac{3}{p}\implies (p - 3 x) (2 p - 3 y) = 2 p^2$. Number divisors of RHS is 6, number solutions is $\le 6/2=3$.

Comment: @Rushi, I know but you wrote "exactly 3 equations" instead of 3 solutions. Read what you wrote in bold.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much @user25406 for pointing this out and my apologies for not understanding before!!

Comment: @DmitryEzhov, why $6/2$? Factors on LHS are not symmetric.

Comment: @cosmo5, in LHS two algebraic factors: $(p-3x)$ and $(2p-3y)$.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov Please see my answer. I got 6 possible *valid* cases. I only argued that some of them are not integers.

Answer (score 2):

$$ 3xy - 2px - py = 0$$

$$ 9xy - 6px - 3py = 0$$

$$ 9xy - 6px - 3py + 2p^2 = 2p^2$$

$$ (3x-p)(3y-2p) = 2p^2$$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\color{red}{(3x-p)}\color{blue}{(3y-2p)} &   x & y\\ \hline
A&\color{red}{1}\cdot\color{blue}{2p^2} &   (p+1)/3 &  2p(p+1)/3 & \color{green}{?}\\ \hline
B&\color{red}{2p^2}\cdot\color{blue}{1} &    p(2p+1)/3 &   (2p+1)/3 & \color{green}{?}\\ \hline
C&\color{red}{2}\cdot\color{blue}{p^2} &    (p+2)/3  &  p(p+2)/3   &\color{green}{?}\\ \hline
D&\color{red}{p^2}\cdot\color{blue}{2} &    p(p+1)/3  &  2(p+1)/3   &\color{green}{?}\\ \hline
E&\color{red}{p}\cdot\color{blue}{2p} &    2p/3 &  4p/3  &\color{red}{✗}  \\ \hline
F&\color{red}{2p}\cdot\color{blue}{p} &    p  &   p &\color{green}{\checkmark} \\ \hline
\end{array}

From the table we come across two cases :

- When $p+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, $A$, $D$ and $F$ each produce one solution.

E.g. for $p=11$, $$ {\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{2}{88}=\dfrac{3}{11},\dfrac{1}{44}+\dfrac{2}{8}=\dfrac{3}{11},\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{2}{11}=\dfrac{3}{11}}$$

- When $p+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, $B$, $C$ and $F$ each produce one solution.

E.g. for $p=7$, $$ {\dfrac{1}{35} +\dfrac{2}{5}=\dfrac{3}{7},{\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{2}{21}=\dfrac{3}{7}},\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{2}{7}=\dfrac{3}{7}}$$

Note that $2p+1 \equiv 0 \equiv 2p+1+3 \equiv p+2  \pmod 3$.

Thus **the conjecture that $1/x + 2/y = 3/p$ has exactly three solutions in positive integers $x$, $y$ for prime $p \ge 5$ is correct!**

---

Thanks to @Servaes for pointing out the critical mistake! :)

Comment: What about $\tfrac{1}{44}+\tfrac{2}{8}=\tfrac{3}{11}$?

Comment: Yes. Fixed. Thanks!